# how to attach a stylesheet directly in a template file in trac framework?

Tags: python, frameworks, trac

I am using trac version 1.0.15 and I used to attach stylesheets using `add_stylesheet` and javascript files using `add_script` methods of trac.These methods add stylesheets to the head section of the html page. But I wish to know how can I attach a stylesheet  using a relative path from the plugin's css directory directly to the `body` section of the html page.

How can I do this? please help me!

Comment: Are you trying to insert the stylesheet to an existing template (such as a template shipped with Trac)? Or do you wish to insert the stylesheet to a template that you developed for you own theme or plugin?

Comment: I am trying to attach stylesheets to the template files (html files) of my own plugin not the one shipped with trac. I wish to know this because, attaching many css, js files in the head tag slows down the page rendering so in order to optimize it I am trying to attach the css, js  files just above the `</body>` tag. I hope that could speed up my site. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to accomplish this would be to first use `add_script` and `add_stylesheet` to add your scripts and stylesheets to the page. Then, inspect the HTML. You'll see entries like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="/chrome/wikiextras/css/phrases.css" type="text/css" />
```

You can then move those elements to `body` of the page (assuming that's allowed by the HTML spec, I don't recall from memory) and remove your `add_script` and `add_stylesheet` calls. The proper path should be clear after you've done those step. The path always starts with `/chrome/`, but depends on your plugin name, package directory structure and contents of your `setup.py`.